# Using \ref in a ylabel of a pgfplot

Tags: cross-referencing, pgfplots

When I use `\label` and `\ref` to distinguish two y axes the marks drawn by `\ref` are no longer on the lines after rotating it together with the rest of the label (see example below). Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis y line*=left, scale only axis,
                 ylabel={estimation 2 \ref{pgf:allsamples}}]
      \addplot[blue,mark=+] table {data2.csv};
      \label{pgf:allsamples}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[axis y line*=right, scale only axis,
             ylabel={estimation 1 \ref{pgf:swingvotes}}, ylabel near ticks]
      \addplot[red,mark=x] table {data1.csv};
      \label{pgf:swingvotes}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ref does not work as expected]

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate on "something went wrong".

Comment: Yep, that description was a bit weak, I hoped the picture would make clear what I mean. Anyway, Christian's patch did exactly what I wanted.
I changed the description a bit so hopefully if anyone else has the same problem they will find this with google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, indeed, a bug in pgfplots: the `\ref` command checks if "it is invoked from within a tikz picture". But this check is buggy because it, well *is* invoked from within a tikzpicture, but the tikzpicture has been interrupted to display a node.

As a result of the bug, the labels have an unexpected displacement.

Until the bug is fixed, you can use the following work-around:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\fixcheck{%
    \def\tikzifinpicture##1##2{##2}%
}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis y line*=left, scale only axis,
                 ylabel={\fixcheck estimation 2 \ref{pgf:allsamples}}]
      \addplot[blue,mark=+] {x+5};
      \label{pgf:allsamples}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[axis y line*=right, scale only axis,
             ylabel={\fixcheck estimation 1 \ref{pgf:swingvotes}}, ylabel near ticks]
      \addplot[red,mark=x] {x};
      \label{pgf:swingvotes}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In all your labels, it adds the `\fixcheck` macro which will simply cause the check to return "false". In that case, `\ref` will add a temporary tikzpicture.