# pgfplots hand-made legend (\label + \ref) fails with custom styles

Tags: cross-referencing, pgfplots

In `pgfplots`, when I use a custom style to plot a line, `\label` the line and then `\ref` to this plot, I am unable to get the desired result.

The desired result would be to get a little line where I am using `\ref`.

The actual result:

- On the first compilation, I get `LaTeX Warning: Reference 'plot:coor' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.`, and the line in the text gets replaced by `??`.
- The second compilation fails with `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/custom' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`.

I'm using:

- `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)`
- `LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>`
- `pgfplots 2011/07/29 v1.5 (git show 1.5-1-gcc2f2d2 )`
- `tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`.

A minimum (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[custom/.style={thick}]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[custom] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,3)};
\label{plot:coor}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
This is \ref{plot:coor}.
\end{document}
```

If I add the custom style to the `axis`-environment, the problem remains. If I copy the `thick` to the arguments of `addplot`, the problem goes away. However, in my real situation, I apply a similar style to four different plots, so I would like to use a custom style. My questions:

- Is this a bug?
- If yes, is it known and is there a workaround?
- If no, how do I `\ref`er to a `\label`ed plot created with a custom style?
- Why is it behaving in this way?

Related but different questions:

- [pgfplots, custom legend and tikz library external](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36786/pgfplots-custom-legend-and-tikz-library-external)
- In an answer to [Using \ref in a ylabel of a pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36917/using-ref-in-a-ylabel-of-a-pgfplot) a bug is mentioned affecting `pgfplots` and `\ref`. If I replace `\ref{plot:coor}` by `{\fixcheck \ref{plot:coor}`, where `\fixcheck` is defined as in the aforementioned question, the problem remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I realised the answer to my own question.

The reason `\ref` won't work is because when `\ref` is invoked, the style defined inside the `tikzpicture` is no longer known. To make it work, use `\pgfplotsset`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{custom/.style={thick}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[custom] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,3)};
\label{plot:coor}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
This is \ref{plot:coor}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yup, that's right, the styles given to the `axis` environment are local. Note that `\pgfplotsset{custom/.style...}` will define a key called `/pgfplots/custom`, while `\begin{tikzpicture}[custom/.style...]` will create `/tikz/custom`. This doesn't matter for plot styles, because pgfplots checks both directories, but if you want to use the plot style with other TikZ objects (like `\draw [custom] ...`), you should use `\tikzset{custom/.style...`.